# How do I repeatedly "listen" for an image to show up in a directory and display it for a few seconds?

Tags: python, asynchronous, opencv

I've been stuck on this for a while, Python keep crashing when I run this and test it. I'm trying to display an image that will get created upon a post request using Flask.  I couldn't figure out how to display it through the request since it kept crashing with OpenCV.  So, I am pursuing a separate script that runs and continuously checks for the image to show up in the directory, display, destroy it, and then checks for the image to show up again (say after 1 or 2 seconds again).

The latest code I tried was this:

```
import os
import cv2
import time

filename = 'lewis.jpg'

def display():
  img = cv2.imread(filename)
  cv2.imshow('img', img)
  key = cv2.waitKey(2000) & 0xFF

if __name__ == '__main__':
  while True:
    display()
      cv2.destroyAllWindows()
      time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Do you control the Flask code?

Comment: I do, I'm just creating a very basic project

Comment: Try changing your Flask code to acquire into a file called `saving.jpg` and then rename that file as `lewis.jpg` when it is saved. That way your code shown here cannot read an incompletely written file. Also handle the error gracefully if you go to open the file and it is not there yet - maybe by waiting 100ms and trying again.

Comment: You could also look at `inotifywait` which would tell you about file creation/deletion events. Or your Flask app could write the image to a Redis queue (`LPUSH`) and your display app could wait on a Redis queue (`BLPOP`).

Answer (score 0):

Your code *would* look about right, if it had a `try` / `except` clause to catch FileNotFoundError. Or consider a "look before you leap" approach:

```
from pathlib import Path

filename = Path('lewis.jpg')
```

and then later, within the infinite loop, use a test like:

```
if filename.exists():
    display()
    ...
```

Comment: Rats, it still doesn't work, I keep getting an error :/